# How to pass two arguments between two views in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am converting a Flask project into Django one.
I have a view1 function that takes user input and passes it to a function1 that returns two variables. Variable x is used in query string and passed to view2. However, I also need to pass variable y to view2 for further operations.
I Flask application I used expression 'global y' but this does not work in Django.
Any ideas,

```
def function1(input):
  #does something
  return x,y

def view1(request):
  form = SomeForm()
  context={'form': form}
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      input = form.cleaned_data['data_from_user']
      # global y --> works only in Flask
      x,y = function1(input)      
      return redirect("view2", x) # goes to path('<str:x>/', views.my_app, name='view2')
  return render(request, "my_app/view1.html", context)

def view2(request, x):
  record = SomeTable.objects.filter(y=y).first()
  context = {'record': record}
  return render(request, "my_app/view2.html", context)
```

Comment: I mean why not just add it as an argument and pass it?

Comment: X and Y represent a name and corresponding code. The url has to contain only the name (aesthetic reasons i guess).

Answer (score 0):

The global *would not* have worked in Flask either: it might have appeared to in a limited development environment, but would certainly fail in production. You *cannot* safely share global data between requests in a multi-process, multi-user environment like a web server.

If you don't want the data in the URL, you need to save it somewhere persistent. In this case the session would be the perfect place.

```
def view1(request):
    ...
    x, y = function(input)
    request.session['y'] = y
    ...

def view2(request, x)
    y = request.session.pop('y', None)
```